# Type mis-match for included library in go

Tags: go

I'm running into an issue with a library I made that I want to include in multiple projects

```
# github.com/pcs-services/message-queue-operator/pkg/controller/messagequeue
pkg/controller/messagequeue/messagequeue_controller.go:167:129: cannot use instance.ObjectMeta.GetUID() (type "github.com/pcs-services/message-queue-operator/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID) as type "github.com/pcs-services/grafana/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID in argument to grafana.DeployGrafana
```

The files are the same in the main project to the

```
$ md5 k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types/uid.go
MD5 (k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types/uid.go) = cc286eae550982db7f93c079e0df1f52
```

```
$ md5 k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types/uid.go
MD5 (k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types/uid.go) = cc286eae550982db7f93c079e0df1f52
```

`k8s.io/apimachinery` is vendored in the main app but not the library.

Comment: Your last paragraph is literally the definition of the problem. It doesn't matter that the two files are the same, the package path that leads to them is different. `github.com/pcs-services/message-queue-operator/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID` != `"github.com/pcs-services/grafana/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID`.

Comment: Are you using DEP? Try running a dep ensure

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
pkg/controller/messagequeue/messagequeue_controller.go:167:129: 
cannot use instance.ObjectMeta.GetUID() (type 
"github.com/pcs-services/message-queue-operator/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID) 
as type 
"github.com/pcs-services/grafana/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types".UID 
in argument to grafana.DeployGrafana
```

So, you're using `github.com/pcs-services/grafana/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types.UID` but imported `github.com/pcs-services/message-queue-operator/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types.UID`. Check your imports and possibly run `dep ensure` (if you're using dep) to copy the correct dependencies to your vendor folder.